# Problem with slash within a query string

Tags: asp.net, query-string, urlencode

I'm using the WebRequest class to make a request to some site. The query string contains a slash (/), which cause to the url to be cut by the site, because it doesn't see it as part of the query string.

The query string is: "my params / separated by slash".

The request:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(
    "http://www.somesime.com/q-my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash"
);
```

What I missing?

EDIT:
After all answers here are update:

I was wrong about query string, it's not actually query string, but the url should look (without "?"):

```
"http://www.somesime.com/q-my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash"
```

The url "http://www.somesime.com/q-my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash" is result of Server.UrlEncode method. The code:

```
var url = "http://www.somesime.com/q-" + 
    Server.UrlEncode(@"my params / separated by slash");
```

EDIT 2:
If I place the resulting url into a browser, everything works.
But if I run it through WebRequest class, the url results as it was called without "/ separated by slash" part

Comment: in your example, there is no querystring. The querystring is the part of the url after a questionmark. Although that might look a bit like a querystring it is, in fact, part of the path.

Comment: Server.UrlEncode will remove the '/'s so won't that mess up your webrequest, assuming that it does use URL routing you just altered the path.

Comment: @F5ToDebug: Server.UrlEncode converts '/' to '%2f'. But the site, I make a request, still see it as '/'

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual code you are missing the ?:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.somesime.com/?q=my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash");
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to put "?" before key name , so try :

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.somesime.com?q=my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at apaches AllowEncodedSlashes option

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

You should be able to enable this through .htaccess or httpd_conf

Answer (score 0):

[UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) it. (You will need a reference to `System.Web` )

```
string url = "http://www.somesime.com/?q=my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash");
var request = WebRequest.Create(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url));
```

Comment: You should only url encode the values, not the entire url, and that is already done...

Comment: Yes, you are correct - only the values should be encoded (presuming they haven't already been).

Answer (score 0):

This part of the URL:

```
/q=my+params+%2f+separated+by+slash
```

is actually a continuation of the URL, the website probably uses some kind of URL routing.  Query strings are denoted by the '?' and seperated by '&'.

If you did need to remove '/' from a URL then HttpUtility.UrlEncode would be the way to go, but this will not benefit you in your case as any encoding done to the URL will almost definitely cause your WebRequest to fail.

Answer (score 0):

?

(Yes, that is what you are missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

$qrypic = 'INSERT INTO tbl_propics (userID,num,imagename,propic) VALUES ("$id","1","http://\graph.facebook.com/\$id/\picture?type=large","1")';