# Send HTTP Request, parameter confusion

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to send a HTTP request to a servers interface.
But I'm really confused about how to specify the parameters I want to send to the servers interface method. What I've done so far.

My server interface only accepts POST requests, that's why I'm using POST and asked if something is wrong with the way I use the parameters.

```
Dim parameters As String = "?text=test&type=person"
Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters)
Dim WebReq As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(NameRecPage), HttpWebRequest)
'NameRecPage is the url

WebReq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Username, Password) 'variables are defined and theier values are valid

WebReq.Method = "POST"
WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length
Dim PostData As Stream = WebReq.GetRequestStream()

PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
PostData.Close()

Dim WebResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(WebReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim Answer As Stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream()
Dim _Answer As New StreamReader(Answer)

Dim inputBuffer As String = _Answer.ReadToEnd()
```

That's my code so far and it's sending a request. But i get an error saying that the first (and i think also the second) parameter is null.

I'm quite unsure about these two line:

```
Dim parameters As String = "?text=test&type=person"
WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Is there something wrong with my parameter syntax?

Are these spellings correct in my content? What is content type about? What does it say and how do I determine which value to put in there?

I don't know if thats the correct value for ContentType, actually I just want to receive some JSON fromatted data returned as string.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: Use WebRequest.Create(url) static method instead.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238773/problem-with-slash-within-a-query-string

Comment: I think this references to GET requests only?

Comment: If your are using the POST method data has to go into the body of the message and not into the url as a querystring. It is also slightly different in how it's formatted. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/158488/How-to-Post-Data-Using-WebRequest-with-Query-Strin

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in

```
WebReq.Method = "POST"
```

which should be `GET`

Comment: thanks for your help, but I know that the interface can only be accessed using POST request. I'll add this to my post, therefore i asked, if maybe something is wrong with the way I specify the parameters.